# Can I reorganize vassals under multiple held titles?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My current character holds 3 kingdom titles, but somehow the vassals have ended up homogenized between them geographically. Is there a way I can reorganize my vassals so that if one of the titles is ever lost I don't end up ruling the Swiss Chesse Confederacy?

Note: I'm already suspecting this is prevented by design so you can't play *de facto* primogeniture under gavelkind (by moving all vassals under the primary title), I currently have primogeniture succession on all 3 titles.

Comment: Short answer: you can do this by revoking the title and giving it to someone who is vassal of the title you want to consolidate under. This costs you quite a bit of tyranny, and also creates a super vassal under the primary title.

Comment: Not exactly a preferable option. I'm not looking to revoke any titles. I understand I'm kind of making de jure vassal claims on one title against another, but I figure because I am both parties its a formality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I know of no painless way to accomplish this. However, there is a way.I usually play as elective, so this is something that comes up very often in my games, as one of the titles might have a different successor than the others leading to loss of some of the titles.

The trick is to destroy all top tier titles except the one you want to be your primary title. You can do this by going to the title screen and clicking the destroy button. Advantages:

- after 100 years the vassals of other titles will become *de jure* vassals of whichever title you kept
- you cannot loose any of the titles that you destroyed
- One kingdom is much easier to manage than three

Drawbacks:

- All the *de jure* vassals of that title in your kingdom will get a -50 opinion modifier "Destroyed liege title."
- If one of your vassals controls a large portion of *de jure* area of one of the titles you are destroying, they could re-create that kingdom title and become independent (they also need to control at least two duchies, which is something you should want to prevent in any event)
- Destroying titles will cost you prestige, and you will also earn less prestige

So my suggestion is do it one title at a time, and do it with a character who has ruled for a long time and might depart from the world soon. Also, first do it with titles where the vassals are unlikely to become powerful enough to re-create the title. This will give you time to reorganize your other vassals in preparation for more titles to be destroyed.

Comment: Keep in mind the -50 modifier is for that character alone, and will disappear as soon as your character dies. They will also immediatly stop bitching about "desires Kingdom X", because that title no longer exists. Are you 100% certain that any vassal can simply create a higher tier title? I've never seen that in my game, and I ruled three kingdoms later consolidated into one. Destroying the titles made everyone happier. See: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/141520/25281 and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/153084/25281

Comment: Advantage: One kingdom is much easier to manage than three. Drawback: Destroying titles will cost you prestige, and you will also earn less prestige.

Comment: Added the suggestions. But yeah, they can actually create higher tier titles and become independent that way. I've become independent that way in one of the previous games. But there are pretty steep requirements so it's not going to happen very often, needing to control a certain proportion of the area of the title + have at least two duchies to create a kingdom. Small kingdom titles are usually at risk of this happening (such as Wales or some Spanish kingdoms).

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for, but you are telling me there's no straightforward mechanic without big penalties. What I expected I guess.